# Python: Limit the maximum amount of decimals in all print calls

Tags: python, numpy, formatting, f-string

I have a script with a lot of print calls.

I want to limit all the printed numbers to a maximum of 5 decimals, but changing it by hand with f_strings or formatting would be a lot of work.

Is there any way to specify at the beginning of the script that whenever I call a print function or use an f string, I do not want to know more than 5 (or n) decimals without having to change the formatting of every call I make?

I just care about the representation of the screen. It does not matter to me if the number under the hood has more decimals.

Essentially, instead of having to rewrite each print to this

`print(f'{value:.6f}')`
I would like somethink akin to this:
`#define max_print_length = 10`

Thanks!

I have looked for ways to try and change the behaviour of the print function or defining some kind of flag at the beggining of the script but, so far I'm empty handed. I found a couple of solutions but they are for  different programming languages.

Comment: perhaps implement some new `print` method, say `myprint`, that simply does `print(f'{value:.6f}')`?

Comment: @Hadar Hi thanks for the suggestion but I am not sure if it would work since the print function changes what it prints quite regularly. Sometimes I just print one variable (print(f"A:{a}")), other times I print three with the same call  (print(f"A:{a}, B:{b}, C:{c}")).

Answer (score 0):

As I do not think there is a method of setting a float precision for the entire code, maybe a not-so-elegant custom print method that takes in multiple parameters would be useful. For example-

```
def myprint(dict_to_print: Dict[str,float], precision:int)->None:
    to_print = f""
    for key, value in dict_to_print.items():
        to_print += f"{key}: {value:.{precision}f}\n"
    print(to_print)

myprint({'1st': 12.9943943504538, '2nd': 9.4093485739048}, 2)
>>> 1st: 12.99
    2nd: 9.41
```

PS. a one-liner:

```
def myprint(dict_to_print: Dict[str, float], precision: int) -> None:
    print("".join([f"{key}:{value:.{precision}f}\n" for key, value in dict_to_print.items()]))
```